# Codeiginiter Code working well in local environtment but not working when deploying at domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-deployment

I'm about to launch a website which I built with codeigniter3. I've made configuration changes such as base_url, database, etc. But it shows me an error like this :

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Home::$home
>
> Filename: controllers/Home.php
>
> Line Number: 11
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/u1532211/public_html/application/controllers/Home.php
> Line: 11 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home/u1532211/public_html/index.php Line: 321 Function:
> require_once

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function select() on null
>
> Filename: /home/u1532211/public_html/application/controllers/Home.php
>
> Line Number: 11
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/u1532211/public_html/index.php Line: 321 Function:
> require_once

Here is my Controller

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MY_Controller 
{

    public function index($page = null)
    {
        $data['title']  ='Homepage';
        $data['content']    = $this->home->select(
                [   
                    'product.id', 'product.title AS product_title', 
                    'product.description', 'product.image', 
                    'product.price', 'product.is_available',
                    'category.title AS category_title', 'category.slug AS category_slug'
                ]
            )
            ->join('category')
            ->where('product.is_available', 1)
            ->paginate($page)
            ->get();
        $data['total_rows'] = $this->home->where('product.is_available', 1)->count();
        $data['pagination'] = $this->home->makePagination(
            base_url('home'), 2, $data['total_rows']
        );
        $data['page']   ='pages/home/index';

        $this->view($data);
    }

}
```

Here is my model

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home_model extends MY_Model 
{
    protected $table    = 'product';
    protected $perPage  = 4;
    

}
```

And here is in my core folder, because i made a custom configuration like this :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $model = strtolower(get_class($this));
        if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'models/'.$model . '_model.php')) {
            $this->load->model($model . '_model', $model, true);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Load view with default layouts
     */
    public function view($data)
    {
        $this->load->view('layouts/app' ,$data);
    }

}
```

Model Core

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Model extends CI_Model 
{
    protected $table ='';
    protected $perPage =5;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
        if (!$this->table) {
            $this->table = strtolower(
                str_replace('_model', '', get_class($this))
            );
        }
    }


    /**
     * Fungsi Validasi Input
     * Rules : Dideklarasikan dalam masing masing model
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(
            '<small class="form-text text-danger">', '</small>'
        );
        $validationRules =$this->getValidationRules();
        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($validationRules);

        return $this->form_validation->run();
    }

    /**
     * Seleksi data per-kolom
     * Chain Method
     */

    public function select($columns)
    {
        $this->db->select($columns);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Mencari suatu data pada kolom tertentu dengan data yang sama
     * Chain Method
     */
    public function where($column, $condition)
    {
        $this->db->where($column, $condition);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Mencari suatu data pada kolom tertentu dengan data yang mirip
     */
    public function like($column, $condition)
    {
        $this->db->like($column, $condition);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Mencari suatu data selanjutnya pada kolom tertentu dengan data yang mirip
     */
    public function orLike($column, $condition)
    {
        $this->db->or_like($column, $condition);
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Menggabungkan table yang berelasi yang memiliki foreign key id_namatable
     */
    public function join($table, $type = 'left')
    {
        $this->db->join($table, "$this->table.id_$table= $table.id", $type);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Mengurutkan data dari hasil query dan kondisi
     * Chain Method
     */
    public function orderBy($column, $order = 'asc')
    {
        $this->db->order_by($column, $order);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Menampilkan suatu data dari hasil query dan kondisi
     * Hasil Akhir Chain Method
     */
    public function first()
    {
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->row();
    }

    /**
     * Menampilkan banyak data dari hasil query dan kondisi
     * Hasil Akhir Chain Method
     */
    public function get()
    {
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }

    /**
     * Menampilkan nilai jumlah data dari hasil query dan kondisi
     */
    public function count()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all_results($this->table);
    }

    /**
     * Menyimpan data baru ke dalam suatu table
     */
    public function create($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    /**
     * Mengubah data yang ada pada suatu table dengan data baru
     */
    public function update($data)
    {
        return $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Menghapus suatu data dari hasil query dan kondisi
     */
    public function delete()
    {
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    /**
     * Menentukan limit data untuk ditampilkan
     */
    public function paginate($page)
    {
        $this->db->limit(
            $this->perPage,
            $this->calculateRealOffset($page)
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Menggantikan offset dengan nilai sesuai halaman 
    */    
    public function calculateRealOffset($page)
    {
        if (is_null($page)|| empty($page)) {
            $offset = 0;
        } else {
            $offset = ($page * $this->perPage) -$this->perPage;
        }

        return $offset;
    }
    /**
     * Membuat pagination dengan style bootstrap 4
     */
    public function makePagination($baseUrl, $uriSegment, $totalRows=null)
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config = [
            'base_url'          => $baseUrl,
            'uri_segment'       => $uriSegment,
            'per_page'          => $this->perPage,
            'total_rows'        => $totalRows,
            'use_page_numbers'  => true,
            'full_tag_open'     => '<ul class="pagination">',
            'full_tag_close'    => '</ul>',
            'attributes'        => ['class' => 'page-link'],
            'first_link'        => false,
            'last_link'         => false,
            'first_tag_open'    => '<li class="page-item">',
            'first_tag_close'   => '</li>',
            'prev_link'         => '&laquo',
            'prev_tag_open'     => '<li class="page-item">',
            'prev_tag_close'    => '</li>',
            'next_link'         => '&raquo',
            'next_tag_open'     => '<li class="page-item">',
            'next_tag_close'    => '</li>',
            'last_tag_open'     => '<li class="page-item">',
            'last_tag_close'    => '</li>',
            'cur_tag_open'      => '<li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">',
            'cur_tag_close'     => '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>',
            'num_tag_open'      => '<li class="page-item">',
            'num_tag_close'     => '</li>',
        ];

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        return $this->pagination->create_links();
    }
}
```

I already tested it on my localhost, it's totally fine and works perfectly, But Why do I get this error when i'm deploying at domain?

Comment: hint: the database part is supposed to be in a model, what is line 11 in your controllers/Home.php ?

Comment: @Vickel  on my Home.php is :
$data['content']    = $this->home->select

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are referring **home** as your database instance.

the error is with the line $this->home->select(); which says you are trying to call a database function with the help of **home** but **home** has never been declared and it's not an instance of Database.

here are steps to troubleshoot.

1. check if you have any configured database with the name **home** in config/database.php. If you don't have anything with the name home then you might be using the default DB array. then you should use $this->db->select()
2. Check if you have loaded **database** library in config/autoload.php. if not then load it
3. if you have configured your project config/database.php with multiple databases you should load the database before using it.

ex:

if your database.php has `$db['default'] = array();` & `$db['home'] = array();` and you want to make use of **home** database then you should instantiate it like

```
 $home = $this->load->database('home', TRUE);
```

and then you can use it.

```
 $home->select();
```